# iPhone dev - Use an NSDate object to create weekly, monthly, or yearly notifications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

does any one have any advice, direction, or sample code that can help me use the NSDate object (added by user) to create either weekly, monthly, or yearly (selected by user) notification pop-ups?  Thanks a ton to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Dev Library has a section on [Local and Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) that should show you example code on how to set them up and add preferences.  Hope it does the trick for you